# How to change all folder icons within a folder windows 10

Tags: windows, directory, icons

I would like to change all folder icons within a folder in Windows 10.

Do I have to do them all manually? Or is there an option to change all icons within that folder?

Comment: You should be able to select the desired folders, right click, take Properties, then pick the Customize tab and customize them all from there.

Comment: Also, this isn't really a programming question! You might try another forum, if my suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work...  I'll try another forum. Thanks!

Comment: SuperUser is the q&a site for this question, within the Stack Exchange network. Note that this is called out in the `windows` tag that you applied to this question.